# Match up to 10 in an array

Tags: code-golf

### Challenge

Given an array of single digit number, work out if any 2 of them add up to 10 and print them out

### Example

**Input**

> (1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7)

This returns `((4,6),(5,5),(3,7))`

**Input**

> (1,2,3,4,5)

This returns `()`. as there is only one 5

**Input**

> (5,5,5,5,5)

This returns `((5,5),(5,5))` as there is odd number of 5s and each 5 can be used only once

### Rules

Here are the rules!

- Assume input will only be an unsorted array of positive single digit integers
- Each number will be pair up only once, which means if there are three 5s it only form 1 pair (5,5). If there are (3,3,7) it will only form 1 pair (3,7)
- For the input: You can use any type of parentheses(or lack of) as long as readers can tell that the input is a single array of numbers.
- For the output: It must look like an array of pairs. Where the array is the same form as your input.(If you did not use any parenheses in your input, you have to use some kind of symbols so that any readers can tell they are pairs in an array)

### Test Cases

```
(1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7) =((4,6),(5,5),(3,7))
(1,2,3,4,5) = ()
(5,5,5,5,5) = ((5,5),(5,5))
(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7)=((3,7),(4,6))
(9,8,7,6,4,4,3,1)=((9,1),(7,3),(6,4))
```

### Good luck!

The `shorter` an answer is, the better!

Edit 1: update the rules and Testcases from comments

Edit 2: update rules to define format of input.

Edit 3: update rules to define format of output. trying to be as accommodating as possible.

Comment: Shouldn't there be 10 different combinations of `(5,5)` for the final test case?

Comment: @Gareth It looks like the values get used up when they make pairs

Comment: Could you post a few more test cases? Perhaps something like `(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7)`

Comment: @Matt edited. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Does the input have to include the parentheses, or can it be inputted as `1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7`?

Comment: @jdstankosky I wasn't sure how array is defined in each languages so I didn't set that as one of the rules. Since it was like that, I am gonna say that you can use any type of parentheses(or lack of) as long as readers can tell that the input is a array of numbers.

Comment: Is the output bound to some rules or are you as lenient as with the input?

Comment: @tomsmeding the output is a bit more stricter. It must look like an array of pairs to any readers. Where you are using the same format for the array as your input.

Comment: Can we assume the input is sorted?

Comment: @GigaWatt the input is not sorted else it would be a bit too easy

Comment: @Gareth i agree, there should certainly be 10 combinations of 5's

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### GolfScript, <strike>45</strike> <strike>42</strike> 37 chars

```
~{([.~11+.])@{1$=.{2$p!\}*!},\;\;.}do
```

The new approach does also take arrays with a single item as input. Moreover, it is several chars shorter.

Previous version:

```
~{$(\)@.2$+10-.{0>{\}*;+}{;[\]p}if.,1>}do;
```

The algorithm used in this code is described as follows:

- Sort the array.
- Take the sum of the first and the last item.

  - If the sum is 10 print both numbers and remove them from the array.
  - If the sum is greater than 10, discard the larger number.
  - If the sum is less than 10, discard the smaller number.
- Loop until the array contains only a single digit or is even empty.

The code expects an array of at least two digits on STDIN.

Examples (see [online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJbOSA4IDcgNiA0IDQgMyAxXSIKfnskKFwpQC4yJCsxMC0uezA%2Be1x9KjsrfXs7W1xdcH1pZi4sMT59ZG87CgoiLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0icHV0cwoKOyJbNSA1IDUgNSA1XSIKfnskKFwpQC4yJCsxMC0uezA%2Be1x9KjsrfXs7W1xdcH1pZi4sMT59ZG87Cg%3D%3D&run=true)):

```
>[9 8 7 6 4 4 3 1]
[1 9]
[3 7]
[4 6]

>[5 5 5 5 5]
[5 5]
[5 5]
```

Answer (score 9):

## Python 2.7 (70)

```
y=input()
while y:
 g=10-y.pop()
 if g in y:y.remove(g);print(g,10-g)
```

Testcases:

```
$ echo '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7]' | python p.py
(3, 7)
(4, 6)
(5, 5)

$ echo '[1,2,3,4,5]' | python p.py

$ echo '[5,5,5,5,5]' | python p.py
(5, 5)
(5, 5)

$ echo '[1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7]' | python p.py
(3, 7)
(4, 6)

$ echo '[9,8,7,6,4,4,3,1]' | python p.py
(9, 1)
(7, 3)
(6, 4)
```

One byte extra for the nice parenthesis.

Comment: I think I replicated this method in PHP, but it only works occasionally and not with all pairs. Any idea why? `<?$a=fgetcsv(STDIN);while($a){$b=10-array_pop($a);if($a[$b]){unset($a[$b]);echo"($b,",10-$b,")";}}`

Answer (score 5):

### Javascript, <s>188</s> <s>183</s> <s>181</s> <s>153</s> <s>141</s> <s>121</s> <s>123</s> <s>112</s> *105* <s>98</s> chars

Golfing in JS is somewhat difficult, but I just wanted to have a bash on this problem, so here's the code:

```
for(a=eval(prompt(i=o=[]));k=a[j=++i];)for(;p=a[--j];)k+p-10||(k=a[i]=a[j]=-o.push([p,k]));console.log(o)
```

Input: e.g. `[1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7]`. Output e.g. `[[4,6],[3,7]]` to the console.

<s>105->98: Used Daniel's awesome algorithm to completely rewrite the code! See [his answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8999/6689) for a readable algorithm.</s> Completely messed up stuff so reverted to **105** chars.

112->105: Initialised `i` to zero, used output of `o.push` to set `k` (`k=a[i]=a[j]=-o.push...`) and logged output to console instead of alerting to eliminate `"["+` and `+"]"` since the console outputs nicely already.

123->112: Now removed outer brackets in output, since golfscript may :) Also finally applied suggestion of removing `|=0`.

121->123: Changed `o+="("+p+","+k+"),"` to `o.push("("+[p,k]+")")` (adds 2 chars :( ) and made `o` an array instead of a string (`o=""`->`o=[]`). Now output isn't wrong anymore (like `((5,5),(5,5),)`).

141->121: From now on assumed that the question meant that we could get input in the language's array format, which in JS's case is `[a,b,c,...]` and made `o`, the output "accumulator" a string instead of an array (`o.push(...),`->`o+=...,`).

153->141: Reset array entries instead of removing them after usage.

181->153: Applied changes to `u=[]`, rearranged loops, `a[i]`&`a[j]`->temp vars, converted if logic and converted int logic to `a[i]|=0`.

183->181: Replaced `i<=0` with `i+1` and the same for `j`.

188->183: Placed `o=[]` inside `prompt()` (<s>`;`</s>) and replaced `for(j=i;` with `for(j=i-1;` (<s>`i==j&&`</s>).

*(Thanks mellamokb, Paul Walls and ryan!)*

Comment: You can replace `i>=0` with `i+1` and `j>=0` with `j+1` to save 2 chars.

Comment: Also, I think you can shave a few characters by using an array to represent which items are already used.  For example, set `x=[]`, then replace the inside of the entire `if` with `o.push("("+a[x[j]=j]+","+a[x[i]=i]+")")`, and the condition on the inner `for` with `j>=0&!x[i]&!x[j]`.  I'm not convinced this can't be golfed further, but I believe it will save 1-2 chars.

Comment: @mellamokb does that really save chars? But replaced the first one :)

Comment: I applied the change to a bit field array (`u=[]` instead of `x`), rearranged the loops to go from 0 upward, assigned `a[i]` and `a[j]` to temp variables to save repeated references, moved some variable initializations into other statements, converted the `if` logic to chained `||` logic, and converted the int parsing to the more succinct `a[i]|=0`, to get a total savings of 30 characters :).  Here's my test harness demonstrating the accuracy of the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/GKUDb/8/, and the 151-character golfed working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/DVtW2/.

Comment: Reproduced 151-character answer for reference: `a=prompt(o=[]).slice(1,i=-1).split(',');for(u=[];k=a[j=++i]|=0;)for(;p=a[--j];)k+p-10||u[i]||u[j]||o.push("("+(u[j]=u[i]=p)+","+k+")");alert("("+o+")")​`.  BTW, you *can* golf in JS, the methods are just different :P

Comment: Shaved off another 11 characters by borrowing the ingenious idea from @air_blob of simply resetting array entries as they are used up (duh!): `for(a=prompt(o=[]).slice(1,i=-1).split(',');k=a[j=++i]|=0;)for(;p=a[--j];)k+p-10||(o.push("("+p+","+k+")"),k=a[i]=a[j]=-1);alert("("+o+")")` ([test harness](http://jsfiddle.net/GKUDb/11/) | [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gGDmq/))  Current solution now beats both `C` and Python implementations!

Comment: @mellamokb I don't have time to get to golfing myself right now but I'll be back! You're a genius, by the way :)

Comment: With your new code using an array, you can save a few more characters by initializing i to `0`.  I only had used `-1` for the convenience of sharing the parameter to `slice`, but `i=0` works as well.  In fact, if you set `i=""`, it coalesces to an integer properly, so you can combine the initialization to `a=prompt(i=o="")...`.  Also, since you are `eval`ing an array, there's no longer a need to convert the entries from string to integer, so you can drop of the `|=0` on `k=a[j=++i]` to save 6 chars total.

Comment: Here's another approach that eliminates the inner `for` loop entirely by using parallel nested counters chained with `||`: `for(a=eval(prompt(j=i=o=''));(p=~~a[--j])||(k=a[j=++i]);)k+p-10||(o+="("+p+","+k+"),",a[i]=a[j]=-1);alert("("+o+")")`.  Sadly, it ends up being 1 char longer than the reduced form from my previous comment, but it may have more yet that can be golfed.

Comment: Array.toString() will save you a few characters as well (i.e. `o+="("+[p,k]+")"`).

Comment: Do you think we may output to the console instead of alerting? Then we could save some chars as well :)

Comment: If you are ok with output like that of golfscript, then you can do this:  `for(a=eval(prompt(o=[])),i=-1;k=a[j=++i]|=0;)for(;p=a[--j];)k+p-10||(o.push("["+[p,k]+"]"),k=a[i]=a[j]=-1);alert(o)`, brings it down to 115

Comment: What golfscript can, we can do too!

Comment: You forgot my suggestion to  initialize i to 0.  You can fold `a=eval(prompt(o=[])),i=-1` into `a=eval(prompt(i=o=[]))` without loss of fidelity, for a further 3 character savings.

Comment: Incorporated mellamokb's suggestion above and a few other shenanigans: `for(a=eval(prompt(i=o=[]));k=a[j=++i];)for(;p=a[--j];)k+p-10||(k=a[i]=a[j]=-o.push("["+[p,k]+"]"));alert(o)`. Down to 107.

Comment: @tomsmeding: You're newest solution is fundamentally broken.  The problem is `i in a` *doesn't* check if `a` has value `i`; it checks if `a` has *index* `i`.  So where it is working, it's working by accident for inputs where the indexes are roughly the same as the values.  Also, in golfing C-style languages, it is generally encouraged to prefer `for` over `while`, because the basic format is the same length (`while()` vs `for(;;)`), but `for` allows the flexibility of squeezing out a few more chars by making elegant use of the three parts.

Comment: Here's my test harness setup with your new code to demonstrate what I mean.  Only two of the test case answers are actually correct: http://jsfiddle.net/GKUDb/16/.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't test properly :) I've tried to get David's algorithm golfed enough but didn't make it in a reasonable number of chars. Reverted now to 105.

Answer (score 3):

### J, <strike>54</strike> <strike>53</strike> <strike>50</strike> <strike>46</strike> <strike>45</strike> 44 characters

```
(>:,.9&-)I.<.4({.,-:@{::)(<.|.)+/|:(1+i.9)=/
```

Usage:

```
   (>:,.9&-)I.<.4({.,-:@{::)(<.|.)+/|:(1+i.9)=/5 5 5 5 5
5 5
5 5
   (>:,.9&-)I.<.4({.,-:@{::)(<.|.)+/|:(1+i.9)=/9 8 7 6 4 4 3 1
1 9
3 7
4 6
```

The algorithm is basically:

- count the instance of each number `+/|:(1+i.9)=/`
- pair the counts of each pair that would add to 10 `(<.|.)` (so 1 and 9, 2 and 8 etc.)
- take the minimum of those counts  (so if you have three 9s but only one 1, you'll only have one `1 9` pair) and drop everything after the first five pairs
- the 5s are a special case so divide that by 2 (`<.4({.,-:@{::)` implements both previous steps)
- take the first five items of the list and output the number and 10`-`the number `(>:,.9&-)I.`

Answer (score 3):

### Python (142)

Input should be given with square brackets instead of round brackets.
http://ideone.com/p2QR11

```
from itertools import*
a=input()
c=lambda:[i for i in product(a,a[1:])if sum(i)==10]
d=c()
while d:print d[0];[a.remove(j)for j in d[0]];d=c()
```

Algorithm:

```
1. Get input
2. Generate all pairs of input where the sum is 10
3. If there are no pairs, then END PROGRAM
4. Take the first pair's items and remove them from the input
5. Go back to step 2
```

If seriously malformed output is allowed **(90)**: http://ideone.com/GR762f

```
a=input()
c=a.count
for i in range(6):print(`i`+`10-i`+' ')*(min(c(i),c(10-i))/(1+(i==5)))
```

Answer (score 3):

### C, <strike>142,138</strike>, 124

```
char*p,*q;
main(int a,char**s){
    for(p=s[1];*p;p++)
        if(q=strchr(p+1,106-*p))a=*q=printf("%c(%c,%c)",38+a,*p,*q);
    puts("()"+a/6);
}
```

Testing:

```
./a.out "(1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7)"
((3,7),(4,6),(5,5))

./a.out "(1,2,3,4,5)"
()

./a.out "(5,5,5,5,5)"
((5,5),(5,5))

./a.out "(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7)"
((3,7),(4,6))

./a.out "(9,8,7,6,4,4,3,1)"
((9,1),(7,3),(6,4))
```

Implementation notes:

- initially a=2 (program has two args), set to 6 (printf prints 6 chars) once a match occurs
- 106 = '0'+'0'+10, i.e. uses the sum of the ascii codes
- 38+a, is either 44/40, i.e. '(' or ','
- By setting string characters to 6 it ensures they wont add to 106 on other passes
- "()"+a/6, is either "()" or ")"

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript - <strike>131</strike> <strike>129</strike> 125 chars

```
for(i=eval(prompt(r=[])),k=j=i.length;j--;)for(m=k;m--;)if(m!=j&&i[j]+i[m]==10)r.push([i[j],i[m]]),i[j]=i[m]=0;console.log(r)
```

I assume, the order of and in the nested result arrays is not compulsory :)

Evaluated test cases:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7] returns [[7,3],[6,4],[5,5]]
[1,2,3,4,5]       returns []
[5,5,5,5,5]       returns [[5,5],[5,5]]
[1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7] returns [[7,3],[6,4]]
[9,8,7,6,4,4,3,1] returns [[1,9],[3,7],[4,6]]
```

**Edit**: As the problem description says 'Array', we're talking about the language specific notation of an array, right?

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 52

```
perl -ne '$a{$y=9-$_}&&0*$a{$y++}--*print"$y,$_"or$a{$_-1}++'
```

Proof :

```
> cat test
1
2
3
4
5
5
6
7
> perl -ne '$a{$y=9-$_}&&0*$a{$y++}--*print"$y,$_"or$a{$_-1}++' < test
5,5
4,6
3,7
```

And there is an ungolfed commented code :

```
while(<>) {     # made by the -n option

    # We are looking for (P,Q) pairs where P+Q=10
    # Each P entry will come in $_="P\n" (because $_ will not be chopped)
    # We choose to store the number of occurence of P in $a{P-1}
    # (For instance, if there have been five '3's in the input, then $a{2}=5)

    $y=9-$_;        # if Q=P-10, then $y=Q-1
    if ($a{$y}) {   # check if there was a Q (so $a{Q-1} != 0)
        $a{$y++}--;   # If so 'consume' this Q, and let $y=Q
        print"$y,$_"; # ... and output "Q,P\n"
    } else {
        $a{$_-1}++;   # P is not forming a new pair, so 'count it'.
                    # $a{$_} would not work because of the un-chopped \n, thus the '-1'
    }

}
```

Maybe the explanations looks like pidgin French (I'm not a native english writer), so if someone wants to edit it and make it more understandable, please do so.

Comment: Seriously, not even one point for this, with the explanations and all ?... :(

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica 70

```
Cases[#//.{x___,n_,y___,d_,z___}/;n+d==10:>{x,y,z,n~f~d},a_~f~b_:>{a,b}]&
```

**Usage**

```
Cases[# //. {x___, n_, y___, d_, z___} /; n + d == 10 :> {x, y, z, n~f~d}, 
a_~f~b_ :> {a,b}] &[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7}]
```

> {{3, 7}, {4, 6}, {5, 5}}

Answer (score 2):

**PostScript (46)**

This uses hand-coded binary tokens, therefore, here is a hexdump:

```
00000000  7b 7b 92 1a 92 3f 7b 32  92 19 92 01 31 30 92 3d  |{{...?{2....10.=|
00000010  7b 32 92 09 92 0b 3d 3d  5b 92 40 7d 69 66 92 1a  |{2....==[.@}if..|
00000020  31 92 87 7d 92 83 92 75  7d 92 65 7d 92 a3        |1..}...u}.e}..|
0000002e
```

I [uploaded the binary file](http://www.mediafire.com/?as1zbr0q2d6hb9l) if you want to try it out.

This expects the numbers to be on the stack. They can be prepended to the code or be supplied on the command line, e.g. when using Ghostscript like so:

```
gsnd -c 2 8 5 5 @ 10_golfed.ps
```

If you insist on array syntax for input, then this requires two more tokens (`aload pop`) right at the beginning. In binary tokens, this is four more bytes.

Un-golfed and commented:

```
{ % stopped                   % we use stopped because we want to catch a
                              % stackunderflow when all numbers have been used up
  { % loop                    % repeat until all numbers have been popped off the stack
    % Test for all numbers on the stack whether they add up to 10 with the topmost number
    count{                    % ... nextNumber number currentTestNumber
      exch                    % ... nextNumber currentTestNumber number 
      2 copy add 10 eq{       % ... nextNumber currentTestNumber number
        2 array astore ==     % ... nextNumber
        % We push "[" on the stack because we want to pop the topmost object after each iteration.
        % As [ is a one byte self delimiting token, this is nice for golfing.
        [ exit                % ... nextNumber [
      }if                     % ... nextNumber currentTestNumber number
      count 1 roll            % number ... nextNumber currentTestNumber 
    }repeat                   % number ... nextNumber currentTestNumber
    pop                       % number ... nextNumber
  }loop                       
}stopped
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP <strike>150</strike> <strike>149</strike> <strike>148</strike> <strike>146</strike> <strike>142</strike> --> 140

Use with PHP CLI.

```
<?$a=fgetcsv(STDIN);for($i=0;$i<$c=count($a);$i++){for($j=$i+1;$j<$c;$j++)if($a[$i]+$a[$j]==10){echo"({$a[$i]},{$a[$j]})";$a[$i]=$a[$j]=0;}}
```

Input: `1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7`

Output: `(3,7)(4,6)(5,5)`

Un-golfed:

```
<?php

$a = fgetcsv(STDIN);
$c = count($a);
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
    for ($j = ($i + 1); $j < $c; $j++) {
        if ($a[$i] + $a[$j] == 10) {
            echo "({$a[$i]},{$a[$j]})";
            $a[$i] = 0;
            $a[$j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 84

Requires input in brackets instead of parenthesis.

```
a=input();r=[]
while a:
 n=a.pop(0);m=10-n
 if m in a:a.remove(m);r+=[(n,m)]
print r
```

For roughly the same answer golfed better see [Daniel's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8999/2621).

Answer (score 1):

## SED, 112 chars

Probably somewhat simpler than the other solutions

```
s/.*/@&;12345678987654321/
:
s/\(@.*\)\(.\)\(.*\)\(.\)\(.*;.*\2.\{7\}\4\)/(\2,\4),\1\3\5/
t
s/^\(.*\),@.*/(\1)/
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 72 with the `-p` flag

```
perl -p -e 's/^/@/;1while s/(@.*)(.)(.*)((??{10-$2}))/($2,$4)$1$3/;s/(.*)@.*/($1)/'
```

Comment: I think the `-p` should be counted since the equivalent would add `LINE: while (<ARGV>){...}continue{die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_}`

Comment: On every automated golf server, this would be counted as 80 bytes, as it requires the shebang `#!perl -p` plus newline.